# Is there is any possibility to run a portable exe in debug mode(step-by-step)?

Tags: debugging, portable-executable

i want to work with portable exe for some research ,here i need some tools to run an PE debug mode ....kindly help me .if any tool is available to run a pe in step-by-step method..

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

use olly debugger to run in step by step mode....

Comment: This. Or you can try IDA pro.